# cron job is not writting the output to output log file correctly

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a cron job(a python program) which starts at 9:30 AM(EDT) every week day and runs till 4:15 PM(EDT). The program automatically terminates after 4:15 PM. The way i set my cron job is like this.

```
30 09 * * 1-5 cd /home/IBpy && python RealTimedata.py >> /home/logs/realtimedata.op 2>> /home/logs/realtimedata.er
```

Now,the problem is with the output logs. Every minute my program is supposed to write like 30-40 lines to output file(realtimedata.op). I am using WIN-SCP to check out my output logs what i found is that the cron job is writing the output logs to log file after 2-3 minutes instead of writing as soon as it arrives. I refresh every 30 seconds and check the output log.
For ex:- say suppose i schedule the program start at 9:30 AM i will be able to check first 3 minutes logs only after 9:34 AM only.

And another thing is that the last 8-10 minutes log data is missing in the file though my program keeps running successfully till the end.
I am unable to find the cause for this. Is this the problem of CRON? or are there any problems with my CRON job scheduling? or is this the problem of WIN-SCP which i am using to check the log?  If this is the problem of WIN-SCP kindly suggest me a better FTP client than the WINSCP to check my files.

Thanks

Comment: Are the clocks of your systems all in sync?

Comment: yes, walter they are in sync.

Comment: Try to find where the problem is: Start python from the commandline on the background: do you have a delay? Make another cron entry which calls a script like `while [ 1 ]; do; sleep 20; date; done and redirect output. Login to the server and see if the logs are delayed there as well.

Comment: thanq walter, there are no delays in my code and i even tried the sample scripts earlier like as u told and everything is working fine with the sample code. This delay problem is happening only with those programs which outputs bulk data i mean to say like 30 to 40 lines every minute. I noticed one more thing that my program is writing to error log file as soon as the error occurs and it is failing to write to output file as soon as an output arrives. Note: i am running the code in a linode's server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data to stdout is buffered, I think in chunks of 4K.
You can try the stdbuf or unbuffer command, as explained on [turn-off-buffering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).
Test which one suits best.

The crontab command will look like

```
30 09 * * 1-5 cd /home/IBpy && unbuffer python RealTimedata.py >> /home/logs/realtimedata.op 2>> /home/logs/realtimedata.er
```

or

```
30 09 * * 1-5 cd /home/IBpy && stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 python RealTimedata.py >> /home/logs/realtimedata.op 2>> /home/logs/realtimedata.er
```

Comment: Really sorry for the late reply. I was busy with some other things. I tried this out today and it really helped me a lot.. thanks thanks for the help.